# OS X Lion : Remove some users folders an replace them by a symbolic link

Tags: osx-lion, symbolic-link, user-folders

I have copied my music, movies and pictures folders to another drive and created symbolic links in my user folder that point the new location.
The links do work, but I cannot remove the original folders. When deleting them after a boot from another system drive, the are recreated in my user folder besides the symbolic links.

Is there a way to remove them ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know if/how it's possible, but I wouldn't advise you to do so anyway.

Comment: I have found a working solution.

Comment: How? Can you post an answer?